# Is it okay to modify a mapped matrix in RcppEigen?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm writing some code in RcppEigen, and I came across this ominous warning in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/vignettes/RcppEigen-Introduction.pdf):

> One must, of course, be careful not to modify the contents of the R object in the C++ code. A recommended practice is always to declare mapped objects as const.

This refers to "mapped" matrices, i.e. matrices in Eigen that use the same memory as the corresponding R object.

Is this warning just about good functional programming practice, or are there other things that can go wrong if I use mapped objects to do modify-in-place?

---

This is a simplified version of what I'm doing in Rcpp:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void modify(Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X) {

    X(0,0) = 0;
    return;
}
```

Which does things like this in R:

```
X <- matrix(1:4, 2) + 0
X
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
modify(X)
X
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

For the particular problem I'm working on I'm getting a 5x speed increase by modifying my matrix in place, so I'm prepared for that small sacrifice in terms of readability and maintainability. As far as I can tell it's working as intended, but I'm worried that I'm inviting some sort of subtle bug some time in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is perfectly ok to modify *provided you remain aware of the side-effect of the variable in R*.

In a purely functional world, you would want no side-effects: inputs are processed and not altered, a result is returned.

Here we have a more hybrid approach. Objects are passed down from R as `SEXP`, and the P stands for pointer---so changes persist.  That confuses some people, and we sometimes have to explain here how to avoid it. :)

But in short you are safe, particularly if just set elements and do not do crazy stuff like altering dimensions etc pp.

Comment: That was so fast that SO won't let me accept the answer for another 10 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Lucky timing. I just sat down to write some other Rcpp-related code, refreshed, saw your question and tried to be helpful ;-)